# Qlikview Bar Chart, clustered to compare dimension vs. average

Tags: charts, qlikview

I would like to create a bar chart where I have one dimension (One Zip code selected) and about four categories that represent that ZIP code only, but have averages of all ZIPs for each category as a bar as well to compare. Is there is way to have the four categories along X axis with their respective bars clustered with an average? as of now, I can only make 8 separate bars, but it would be much better if I could have 4 sections with two joined bars for illustrative purposes. Also -- how do I denote one bar as the average (i.e., how do you create legend that displays what the bar color means, because I will want to have the average be a separate color than the selected ZIP's bars).

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get it. Can you please add some example data. What are your categories? You say you have foru of them and one dimension but later you say you have 8 bars!?

Comment: There are 8 total bars, four x axis categories and 2 bars for each (one for the summed category and one to convey the average).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess about your data:

```
Table:
Load zip, 
     value
inline
[
  zip, value
  1000, 17
  2000, 13
  3000, 16
  4000, 11
  1000, 12
  2000, 19
  3000, 16
  4000, 11
];
```

And you want 8 bars in total, grouped by the zip. One for the `sum` and one for `avg`.

In my dashboard I get:

[image]

**SO - 18512847** is a simple bar diagram with *zip* as dimension. And I have two
formulas.

```
Description   Definition
sum           =sum(value)
avg           =avg(value)
```

HTH